# getting around the 1000 file per directory limit

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I just learned from the console of google app engine that there is a 1000 file per directory limit. This is a real bummer and completely unexpected. I may have to change a lot of what was designed for my application.

The application has some entities on the datastore and these entities may have a link to an image. originally I expected to upload all the images together with the application as static files. But there could be 10,000 images or more.

What solution do you recommend? using another service for serving the images and just providing the link to this other service in the entity? Is there a service inside google apps for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) for your images. You can also consider a [Blobstore service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) within the App Engine itself.

It is a better idea than uploading them as static files, considering how many images you have. There is also a limit on the total size of an app code that you may run into. Plus, it will be easier to upload new versions.

Comment: thanks, I started using cloud storage. I have started uploading images manually as I have not looked at the API yet. Do you know if there is a way to make all files public by default?

Comment: Use https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil. Then making all images public is a single command: `gsutil acl set public-read gs://bucket/*`